# verilog-mode AUTOARG on SV packages

Tags: emacs, verilog, system-verilog

does verilog-mode AUTOARG supports publishing ports that are of system-verilog package type?

I realized that when I tried to do this:

```
`include "something_pkg.sv"
```

```
module something(/*AUTOARG*/);
input some_pkg::tx_something busA;
```

It actually provided me this:

```
module something(
/*AUTOARG*/
// Inputs
some_pkg::tx_something);
input some_pkg::tx_something busA;
```

when I actually wanted this:

```
module something(
/*AUTOARG*/
// Inputs
busA);
input some_pkg::tx_something busA;
```

Comment: Why bother with AUTOARGS in this situation? Just do module something(input some_pkg::tx_something busA);

Comment: Yea I think that's what I'm gonna go ahead with. Fortunately upper level AUTOINST is able to correctly match the package type connections. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide verilog-mode with the suffix used by typedefs.

```
// Local Variables:
// verilog-typedef-regexp: "_[tT]$"
// End:
```

In your case it would be the following, but it is suggested to follow a standard naming convention within your codebase.

```
// Local Variables:
// verilog-typedef-regexp: "tx_something$"
// End:
```

https://veripool.org/verilog-mode/help/#verilog-typedef-regexp